# Set XML string using node.innerXML - use of prefix causes error

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I am creating a huge xml from DB and most of it's part is hard-coded(pre-defined values),so I decided to create string using StringBuilder and assigning it to node's InnerXML but prefix used for one of the attribute is not allowing me to set the string stating "Prefix not declared".

```
XMLNode addr = DocumentElement.createElement("element","address",null);
addr.InnerXML = "<test><s1>ttt</s1><s2 xsi:type="test">yyy</s2></test>";
```

prefix xsi is causing the error here. Is there any workaround for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is:

Firstly simply create XMLDocument and assign plain innerXML without namespace and prefixes as

```
  XmlDocument ccda_xDoc = new XmlDocument();
  ccda_xDoc.LoadXml("<ClinicalDocument></ClinicalDocument>");

  XmlElement root = ccda_xDoc.DocumentElement;
  root.InnerXml = @" My XML String without Prefix for any namespace";
```

Then Search for the node where you want to apply prefix to and add attribute with prefix:

```
XmlNode xsiValue = root.SelectSingleNode("encounter/code[@code='99201']");
XmlAttribute xsitype = structuredBody.CreateAttribute("sdtc", "valueSet", "urn:hl7-org:sdtc");
xsitype.Value = "2.16.840.1.113883.3.464.1003.101.12.1047";
xsiValue.Attributes.Prepend(xsitype);
```

Finally Apply namespaces to root node as :

```
ccda_xDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
ccda_xDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
ccda_xDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:voc", "urn:hl7-org:v3/voc");
ccda_xDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:sdtc", "urn:hl7-org:sdtc");
```

Answer (score 0):

xsi seems to be a namespace. You will need to either declare that namespace or not use it. Using it without declaring it is invalid.

Comment: Yes,I have already appended this attribute to root node. xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" But still this error occurs.

Comment: Then maybe you can post your code? Our debugging skills are somewhat lacking if we have to read your thoughts over tcp/ip :)

Answer (score 0):

Had some similar problem, the only way I found to fix this problem, is to **add the needed namespace** to your `InnserXml`:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xdoc.LoadXml("<Document xmlns=\"www.abc.com\" xmlns:xsi=\"w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"></Document>"); 

XmlNode t = xdoc.CreateElement("element", "t", null); 
t.InnerXml = "<originalText xmlns:xsi=\"w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><reference xsi:value=\"testVal\"/></originalText>"; 

xdoc.FirstChild.AppendChild(t);
```